# 'Absolute' position elements to NOT show up when placed outside the confines of parent?

Tags: css

How can I get a child div which is positioned absolutely to not show up when its placed outside the reach of its parent?

https://jsfiddle.net/knp9ebys/9/

```
.papa {
  background:red;
  overflow:auto;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
}

.baby {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

Comment: `overflow:hiddend` + `position;relative` ?

Comment: Thanks. This seems like the only answer, but I was hoping specifically that there is way to do this while still using position: absolute

Comment: You can keep `position: absolute` in your `.baby`, just change `overflow: auto` to `hidden` and add `position: relative` in your `.papa`. https://jsfiddle.net/knp9ebys/19

Comment: I was talking about the parent element not the child

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.papa {
  background:red;
  overflow:auto;
  width:90px;
  height:90px;
  position:relative; /* add this line */
  overflow:hidden; /* add this line */
}

.baby {
  position:absolute;
  top:100px;
  left:100px;
  width:25px;
  height:25px;
  background:blue;
  color:white;
}
```

If you add `position:relative;` to the parent element then the child element can be positioned within the context of the parent. Adding `overflow:hidden;` is the trick because this will remove scroll bars... and since the positioning of the child element is outside the parent's bounds, it will make the child appear to be hidden from view.